# Chrome extension to edit google's background color

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have searched this for the past three hours and haven't found anything that will **work**.

How can I write a chrome extension to change google's background color using javascript.

I'm not sure if this is the right way to do this, but here we go!  This is the javascript that I want to "inject" into google's website.:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.body.style.background = ‘red’;
}
```

Please tell me if there is something wrong with that code, thanks :D.

EDIT:  This is what I have so far in my manifest file (manifest.json):

```
{
    "name": "BetterGoogle",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "A Better Google....",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts" : [{
        "matches" : [ "*://*.google.com/*"],
        "js" : ["bettergoogle.js"]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried that yet? What happens when you try and do that?

Comment: Nothing. I can't get it to work yet.  I think it might have to do with my manifest file

Comment: Okay, then post your manifest file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using smart quotes, which break JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.body.style.background = ‘red’;
}
```

Use straight quotes:

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.body.style.background = 'red';
};
```